# Cannot import "org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database" in KTOR

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, ktor

I was recently working on a MySQL database and wanted to use the database as my data source in KTOR. To use the database, I decided to use the **org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database**
and ***javax.sql.DataSource*** imports. I'm working in IntelliJ.

My test code looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import javax.sql.DataSource

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

val databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/databaseName"
val username = "root"
val password = " "

// Create a DataSource object
val dataSource: DataSource = Database.connect(
    url = databaseUrl,
    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    user = username,
    password = password
)
```

Somehow, I can't import the ***org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database*** , even though I added the dependency in my **build.gradle.kts** file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.mysql.jdbc:mysql-connector-java:8.0.22")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.18.7")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-test-host:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}
```

I tried **syncing the gradle file, rebuilding the project and cleaning the project**. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it by using a different dependency in my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:0.41.1")
```

Instead of:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.18.7")
```